# Is there a web application layer over AdventureWorks?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, adventureworks

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented a web UI on top of the [AdventureWorks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124501%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) database?  IOW, I'm not looking for just a application data layer on top of the schema.  Rather, I'm wondering whether anyone has created an ecommerce front end on top the AdventureWorks schema?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good chance to try [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) (point it at a database and generate a web application that supports basic CRUD procedures).

Comment: I clarified the question.  Not looking for an application data layer on top of the schema but rather an entire application.

Comment: @Mitch - *gasp* An MVP forgot about Dynamic Data!? Hehe. It seems like a lot of people have forgotten about Dynamic Data. Microsoft was big at promoting it for a while and then everything dropped off.

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL Server Samples Portal Page](http://msfteeprodsamples.codeplex.com/) has an end-to-end product sample called [Storefront](http://msfteeprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!Readme_Storefront&referringTitle=Home) which uses the AdventureWorks database as the backend:

> Scenario
>
> A developer wants to implement an e-commerce Web site. The Web site
>   should offer additional product recommendations based on the contents
>   of the shopping cart (product up sell).
>
> Languages
>
> Transact-SQL, XML, XSD, Visual C#, and Visual Basic.

Comment: The sample storefront can be found here: https://github.com/oigbokwe73/AdventureWorks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate one with [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) (free)

There are commercial products that can generate an entire application by pointing at a database, [IronSpeed](http://www.ironspeed.com/products/Overview.ApplicationDevelopment.aspx?c=Google), for example. (Has a trial version)

Comment: I clarified the question.  Not looking for an application data layer on top of the schema but rather an entire application.